# How to force emacs to open a file always as a new frame rather than a new window

Tags: frames

Assume that I have already opened a file with emacs. Is it possible to force emacs to re-open that file in another frame when I re-open that file intentionally or a third party program open that file with emacs ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use **`C-x 5 f`** instead of `C-x C-f` or `C-x 4 f`. Or set `pop-up-frames` to `t` and use `C-x 4 f`.

If you just want to open the *currently visited* file in another frame, use **`C-x 5 2`**.

Comment: Do you mean to put (setq pop-up-frames t) ?

Comment: Drews, your solution works if I re-open that file from emacs interface, but what if I click on the file in my system (suppose that in my system opening that file is assigned to emacs)? This was my main motivation of this question.

Comment: Dunno - perhaps you need to use `emacsclient` and perhaps it has a switch (option) for opening in a separate frame. You might also need to set `pop-up-frames`. Perhaps someone else can help with that question.